# Connection to a MySQL server through a SSH tunnel using Swift 4?

Tags: mysql, swift, ssh

Did anyone ever did (or I should say coded) a connection to a MySQL server through a SSH tunnel using Swift 4?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** connect to host over SSH using [Shout](https://github.com/jakeheis/Shout) framework:

```
let ssh = try SSH(host: "example.com")
try ssh.authenticate(username: "user", privateKey: "~/.ssh/id_rsa")
```

**You can connecet ONLY over privateKey**

**2)** Execute mysql command over linux command line:

```
let jsonResult = try ssh.execute("mysql -uLOGIN -hHOST -pPASS -Bs testDB -e \"SELECT json_arrayagg( json_merge( json_object('PersonID', PersonID), json_object('FirstName', FirstName))) from Persons;\"")
```

You will get JSON-string of mysql query result to jsonResult value.